# Python 'Grab' module cut the address after 'sharp' symbol

Tags: python, curl

My problem is when I try to get `grab.response.url` property the address isn't full. For example: redirected address has the url `http://foreignsite.com/post#status=ok` - so I got only `http://foreignsite.com/post`. Does Grab have the property to get full address? Or should I use native `urllib2` to achieve my aim?

Comment: This which is after the sharp symbol seems to be meant to be a query param... but the correct way to have query params in a URL is by preceding them with a `?`, not a `#`, which leads me to believe that Grab is leaving this part out because it's invalid. Does this URL really belong to an external site?

Comment: Yes, the link belongs to external site, so I can't change "#" symbol to "?".
But GET-params (using "?") are received correctly and not cut by Grab-module

Comment: So I think this confirms what I said previously. Mounting the URL the correct way (using `?` instead of `#`) had Grab not to discard the query params anymore, right?

Comment: You are right, but I cant change it on external site :) my task is to obtain the value of 'status' parameter after '#' symbol. Can the Grab help me?

Comment: Honestly I've never used Grab (that's why I'm trying to help in the comments instead of posting an answer) but, if the URL can't be mounted the right way, I'd guess your best bet would be using `urllib2` as you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I will use `urllib2` in case of emergency. I hope that `Grab` module has the stated functionality